# qt model как обновить row

Tags: qt

```
void MainWindow::startUpload(int ID, QString NAME)
{
    qDebug() << ID;
    qDebug() << NAME;
    QSqlRecord recordAddFilePath = model->record();
    recordAddFilePath.setValue(model->fieldIndex("file_path"),NAME);
    qDebug() << "filling Attach fielepath" << model->insertRecord(ID,recordAddFilePath);
}
```

при таком раскладе добавляет новую строку в таблицу, а мне надо чтобы были изменения в текущей строке (ID)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertRecord()` добавляет строки. Для обновления используйте `setRecord()`:

```
model->setRecord(ID, recordAddFilePath)
```

Comment: Получилось. Только при добавлении остальные данные из таблицы пропадают. Пытаюсь понять в чем дело...